# php TCPDF ability to edit outputted text

Tags: php, pdf, field, edit, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF to create pdf documents, all that is fine and dandy. I've been trying to find some documentation on how to be able to edit written text.

So for example I'm using

```
$pdf->writeHTMLCell($width, 0, '', '', 'this is printed to my pdf!', 0, 0, 0, true, $align);
```

This outputs when the new PDF is rendered and that's fine. I want the ability to view my newly rendered PDF and be able to double click (or single click, whatever) the printed text and change it on the fly in my web browser.

Essentially I want to be able to enable a "editable" flag like you can in html with divs.

Does anyone know if this is possible or how to accomplish it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to edit a PDF is by using an application that has this ability built-in. Adobe Acrobat Professional and Adobe Illustrator are two of the better known options for editing PDFs. There are probably thousands of shareware packages that do this as well. But there is no "editable" flag that you can enable that will automatically make the PDF editable in any of the common PDF viewer applications.

Comment: why not create a library for editing pdf?